# c programming grocery calculator

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop, while-loop

```
float calculateTotalCost(float*itemCosts, int itemCount);

int main()
{
    int itemCount = 0;
    float itemCosts[50];
    char itemName[50];
    char choice;
    printf("Welcome to Grocery Shop\n");

    do {
        printf("Enter item name: ");
        scanf("%s", itemName);
        printf("Enter cost for %s: RM", itemName);
        scanf("%f", &itemCosts[itemCount]);
        itemCount++;
        printf("Do you want to add another item?(yes/no): ");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    } while (choice == 'yes' || choice == 'Yes');

    float totalCost = calculateTotalCost(itemCosts, itemCount);
    printf("\nTotal cost: RM%.2f\n", totalCost);
    return 0;
}
    
float calculateTotalCost(float*itemCosts, int itemCount)
{
    float totalCost = 0;
    int i;
    int itemCounts[50];

    for (i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i)
    {
        totalCost += itemCounts[i];
    }

    return totalCost;
}
```

I want to calculate the grocery items but the output not as expected what I want. Did you know where can i fix my code? I am newbie here

Comment: Why is `itemCosts` not used in `calculateTotalCost`? Turning on all warnings would have brought this to your attention. Further, `itemCounts` in this function is uninitialized when accessed.

Comment: @megat khairie,  `scanf("%c", &choice);` --> `scanf(" %c", &choice);` is 1 fix among the many  problems.  Enable all warnings.

Comment: `choice` can only hold a single character, not multiple characters like `yes`.

Comment: Please provide a minimimal reproducible example, ie compilable code, sample data, expected output from that sample and current output from that sample

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help,
if(string1== string2)
That will compare the addresses of the char arrays and these will always be different. Use
if( strcmp( string1, string2 ) == 0 )
instead. strcmp() will compare the contents of two NUL terminated char arrays ("strings" in C).
Commented the wrong code.

Code:

```
float calculateTotalCost(float*itemCosts, int itemCount);
int main() {
    int itemCount = 0;
    float itemCosts[50];
    char itemName[50];
    char choice[10];
    printf("Welcome to Grocery Shop\n");
    do {
        printf("Enter item name: ");
        scanf("%s", itemName);
        printf("Enter cost for %s: RM", itemName);
        scanf("%f", &itemCosts[itemCount]);
        itemCount++;
        printf("Do you want to add another item?(yes/no): ");
        scanf("%s", choice);
    } while (strcmp( choice, "yes" ) == 0 );
    float totalCost = calculateTotalCost(itemCosts, itemCount);
    printf("\nTotal cost: RM%.2f\n", totalCost);
    return 0;
}
float calculateTotalCost(float*itemCosts, int itemCount)
{
    float totalCost = 0;
    int i;
    //int itemCounts[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
            totalCost += itemCosts[i];
    }
    //  for (i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    // {
    //     totalCost += itemCounts[i];
    // }

    return totalCost;
}
```